# Creating a big query table A from another table B (400 columns) but add an extra column(ID) to table A and cluster on column ID

Tags: google-bigquery

I was trying to figure out an easy and fast way to create a table A from another table B which has more than 400 columns. Just a create or replace table statement as below would have worked.

```
create or replace table A
 AS select * from B where 1=2
```

However, I need to create table A with an extra column as ID and also need to add clustering on this column ID. Altering the table later will also do but I understand that I cannot add clustering once the table is created. I do not want to write a DDL specifying all 400 columns.  Can this be achieved in an easy and faster way?

I was also looking at options to create table dynamically by using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS information. However, I am not yet sure of that.

Comment: just add your clustering options before your AS statement

Comment: @Pentium10, I tried that and later posted this question. As I mentioned, the column that I need to cluster is not part of table B. that is create or replace table A cluster by ID as select * from table B where 1=2 is giving me error of unrecognized name ID. so this doesn't work.

Comment: `create or replace table A cluster by ID as select B.*, "one" as ID from table B`

Comment: Thank you @Pentium10.Dint think of this. This worked!